# How to open custom wiki page subdomain (e.g. moveit.ros.org) and its experience

Tags: ros, documentation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

First, please don't get me wrong, I don't mean I want to open a custom domain.

MoveIt! project uses [moveit.ros.org](http://moveit.ros.org/) for their wiki contents ([that are stored on github according](https://github.com/tork-a/rtmros_nextage/issues/12#issuecomment-56272998) to @Dave Coleman) instead of wiki.ros.org.

Question-1. How is it possible to open a custom sub domain (again I have no interest in doing that. This question has just lingered in mind for a long time)?

Question-2. It looks like running the own server to generate the own html format from `.rst` files. Maybe I like to ask the maintainers @Sachin Chitta @hersh @acorn about its experience, especially the downside, since ROS wiki as I'll mention below has a lot of advantages.

---

Background of this question: While I like ROS wiki with lots of useful macros that are specific to ROS world. I'm also a fan of aethetics aspect of ROS wiki. And using ROS wiki for all documentation gives a sense that all information regarding ROS is centralized under ros.org, which is a huge plus for both beginners and advanced users IMO. On the other hand, we have a kind of strong motivation to keep all resources including document files in our repositories for the maintainability and portability (I assume that's the same with the decision MoveIt! team?). Currently I can't think of any easy way to synchronize raw text documents on ROS wiki to the external sites.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/193644/how-to-open-custom-wiki-page-subdomain-(e.g.-moveit.ros.org)-and-its-experience/) by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10937 on 2014-09-27

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I totally agree with the urge to keep document files in the same repository as the code.

The only downside I have seen to running your own documentation website is that you have to run a website.  That said, if all you're doing is hosting a bunch of auto-generated pages, there will be a bunch of up-front work to set it up and then sporadic bursts of work when things break, or it gets hacked or whatever.

I'm pretty sure that doing a subdomain is just a matter of 1) running a webserver on a computer with a static IP address and 2) getting the (super-)domain owner to add your webserver's address into their server configuration as a subdomain.

---

Originally posted by [hersh](https://answers.ros.org/users/97/hersh/) with karma: 1351 on 2014-09-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-09-29**:
Couldn't we come up with a way to integrate those *auto-generated pages* into the ROS wiki? That way storing documentation sources in versioning systems becomes possible for everyone.

**Comment by [hersh](https://answers.ros.org/users/97/hersh/) on 2014-09-29**:
It already IS integrated, to some extent.  Look at http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/rviz_plugin_tutorials/html/display_plugin_tutorial.html for instance.  Sure it's a separate page, but the ROS wiki has a link to it (here: http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/Tutorials/Plugins%3A%20New%20Display%20Type )

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-09-30**:
I know the 'doc' links, but I was thinking more along the lines of actually integrating the output of the generation process into the wiki pages themselves (instead of linking to them). It's probably not a good idea to generate moinmoin code directly, but embedding something would be nice.

**Comment by [hersh](https://answers.ros.org/users/97/hersh/) on 2014-09-30**:
I'm sure it's possible to auto-generate wiki content and post it with a script.  You could even read and archive it with a script.  However anyone wanting to do such a thing should really talk to the OSRF folks first - last I knew ros.org was really overloaded.

**Comment by [Dave Coleman](https://answers.ros.org/users/1279/dave-coleman/) on 2014-09-30**:
Indeed it seems like ROS packages could benefit from using the auto-generated API docs more often, and better integrating them into ros.org kind of like how ompl does: http://ompl.kavrakilab.org/tutorials.html

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2014-09-30**:
Yeah, we have considered some sort of embedding of generated documentation into the wiki pages using a wiki macro. There are some difficulties related to this approach in terms of the output from generated docs. I think something like GitHub's rendered README.{md,rst,etc...} files would be nice.

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2014-09-30**:
Another approach is what's referred to as an "un-wiki", which is like the ros2 design website: http://design.ros2.org/ Where every page is generated from documents in a git repo and each page has an edit button which takes you to something like prose.io and changes go through pull requests.

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2014-09-30**:
This "un-wiki" is basically provided by readthedocs.org, which I have taken to using for hosting of docs lately: http://catkin-tools.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ (every page there has an edit on github button) Other options we have looked into: gitbook (https://www.gitbook.io/)

**Comment by [Dave Coleman](https://answers.ros.org/users/1279/dave-coleman/) on 2014-09-30**:
+1 to these ideas.

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2014-10-01**:
+1 for those ideas. I'm just afraid that once maintainers per each package started using different domain, information would get distributed...Right now ROS is so great where I can confidently Google only within [`site:ros.org KEYWORD`](http://goo.gl/71Z0K2) to find the info I want.